# Tried to move blogs to a new server - "white screen of death"

Tags: migration, fatal-error

I tried to migrate my old blogs to a new server. The domain remained the same (it was also transfered to the new server). To perform this task I tried to follow these steps: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Keeping_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs

When I now visit the moved blogs, I get nothing more than the "infamous white screen of death".

The wordpress version seems to be 4.1.2
The moved blog should be found at http://yeara.net/odysseus/
The old blog is at http://speendo.cassiopeia.uberspace.de/odysseus/

Can you help me to get this straight?

(X-post: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/server-migration-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: You appear to be outputting PHP. You should speak to your host.

Comment: hm, this is my private server - I am my own host ... can you explain your assumption?

Comment: Please provide [debugging information](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), because a WSOD isn't very specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not have configured Apache. Add this line in your `apache2.conf` file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

Evidently, you should make sure you actually have [installed and activated the PHP module](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.debian.php) first and foremost (the above Apache directive might not even be necessary in this case). In this regard, you can visit the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/` folder and look for the `php5.load`, `php5.conf` files.

Answer (score 2):

So your domain at yeara.net/odysseus loads the following in plain HTML:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

 /**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
 define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

 /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
 require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Have you confirmed that PHP is installed on your new server?

Comment: php is definitely installed. However, obviously the file does not get parsed. I try to find out why...

Comment: In fact, php was installed and activated, however it was not enabled for the user directories. This can be done in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a problem with file permissions, maybe related to the method you use for uploading the files, or as @webtoure pointed out with your apache set-up. The content @DaleAllen pointed out is the `index.php` of your WordPress installation. More critical I can see the content of your `wp-config.php` by directly pointing at it.

Take a look at the codex articles:

- [Changing File Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)
- [Hardening WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/)

to change the file permissions accordingly.

*Do **NOT** forget to change all security relevant information!* Because if I can see it, everybody can.

Comment: thanks for this hint! I changed the file permissions. The problem remains however...

Comment: @Marcel I can see the site. But you got some message about »Notice: wp_register_script was called incorrectly. (...)« that you should fix.

Comment: where do you find this message? Thank you once more.

Comment: @Marcel It showed at the very top of your site. When viewing it xx minutes ago. Now the site doesn't load anymore, so whatever you did in the meantime broke it again.

Comment: @Marcel The server responds with an `500 Internal Server Error` right now, it may be a faulty `.htaccess` involved.

Comment: @Marcel Is your last comment directed at me or at webtoure? I kind of feel like you should accept the answer most helpful for solving your problem, but maybe you did and at the end it is absolutely up to you of course.

Comment: @ialocin This is a bit of a strange situation. What exactly does the accepted answer provide? PHP was installed but not enabled to work with Apache? File permissions were to blame? The `.htacess` file was faulty after all? We are left in mystery. :)

Comment: @Marcel No worries! All is fine with me, I guess I just wasn't sure about the situation, or better, if it makes sense.

Comment: @webtoure Sorry for the confusion I caused! In fact your answer was most helpful ialocin. But the cause of all the troubles in the very first place was, that php was not activated for the user directories. Dale Allen therefore was closest. I supposed that you wouldn't care about the points as you have so many - however, if you do, I will happily accept your answer as it was so helpful.

Comment: @Marcel Hmm, still a bit unclear but I understand that [ialocin's](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/22534/ialocin) answer was the most helpful then, correct? This might be useful for the next potential user coming here with the same issue. :)

Comment: @webtoure why don't you upvote it, then ;-) the original problem was in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/` (just as you suggested). So I really made a mistake accepting Dale Allens answer...

Comment: @Marcel Now I just feel bad. :( I am not helping here for points, I am here to interact with people and find solutions to problems (sort of like puzzles if you will). Please mark the best solution so that others can benefit from it and not because you feel somebody or somebody else deserves it. :) This is your right and privilege! :)

Comment: @webtoure well, as I said, the original problem was really in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf`. Therefore your answer deserves to be selected. There were different problems afterwards addressed by ialocin. I would put it this way: your answer solved the original question, ialocin helped *me* the best. I am grateful for all helpful posts here!

Comment: @Marcel I did upvote his answer but it is your decision of course.

Comment: @webtoure let's see what ialocin says... both of your answers would deserve to be selected!

Comment: @Marcel As said I'm fine with whatever - so all is good!

Comment: @webtoure Your answer solved the main problem, so yours definitely deserves to be the accepted answer. Aside from that see my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the old blog and new blog have different domains then they didn't not remain the same. Share:

- current exact URL to the home page is intended to be?
- old exact URL to the home page was?

Without knowing more it seems like either a URL/directory issue or perhaps an issue with the files/database migration.

Comment: I think this is a misconception. The old domain was http://yeara.net/odysseus/ just as the new domain (also http://yeara.net/odysseus). As I moved the domain (yeara.net) to the new server, I cannot reach the old server at this address anymore. http://speendo.cassiopeia.uberspace.de/odysseus/ is the address, the host of the old server provides.